# Django inline has no ForeignKey

Tags: django, inline

I have on error now. It's inline error, I trying to find the solution, and I'd tried for all day long but failed. I'm sorry about if this question is very easy and repeated.

This is error, when I try to use inline it shows

```
<class 'brick.admin.AdminRoomStateInline'>: (admin.E202) 
'brick.RoomInfomation' has no ForeignKey to 'brick.RoomInfomation'
```

models.py

```
class RoomInfomation(models.Model):

    roomNum = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, primary_key=True)
    roomFloor = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    startPointX = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    startPointY = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    #referencing 
    userInfo_RoomReservationFK = models.ForeignKey('UserInfo', null=True, blank=True)
    compInfo_RoomInfoFK = models.ForeignKey('CompanyInfomations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    companyRoomTypeInfo_RoomInfoFK = models.ForeignKey('CompanyRoomTypeInfomations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % str(self.PositiveSmallIntegerField)

class RoomState(models.Model):
    roomReservation_roomStateFK = models.ForeignKey('RoomInfomation')
    reservationBlock = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    reservated = models.BooleanField(default=False)                                         
    reservatedDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    reservationFirstDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    reservationEndDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    checkoutTime = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    checkinTime = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

admin.py

```
class AdminRoomStateInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = RoomInfomation
    extra = 8
#    list_display = [
#              'roomReservation_roomStateFK',
#              'reservationBlock',
#              'reservated',
#              'reservatedDate',#예약을 진행했던 날짜
#              'reservationFirstDate',
#              'reservationEndDate',
#              'checkoutTime',
#              'checkinTime',
#            ]
#    inlines = [AdminRoomInfomationInline,]

class AdminRoomInfomation(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fields = [
          'compInfo_RoomInfoFK',
          'companyRoomTypeInfo_RoomInfoFK',
          'userInfo_RoomReservationFK',
          'startPointX',
          'startPointY', 
          'roomNum',
          'roomFloor'
         ]
    inlines = [AdminRoomStateInline,]


#class RoomState(admin,ModelAdmin):
#admin.site.register(RoomInfomation)
#admin.site.register(RoomState, AdminRoomState)
admin.site.register(UserInfo, AdminUserInfo)   
admin.site.register(RoomInfomation, AdminRoomInfomation)
admin.site.register(RoomState)
```

I double check that may not tried, for example, when I'd changed inline

```
class AdminRoomState
```

to

```
class AdminRoomInfomationInline
```

error

```
<class 'brick.admin.AdminRoomStateInline'>: (admin.E202) 
'brick.RoomInfomation' has no ForeignKey to 'brick.RoomState'
```

Comment: In `AdminRoomStateInline ` the model you pass is `RoomInformation` - should it be `RoomState`? Also, in your models I don't believe your foreign keys should be strings, with single quotes around them.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works! I couldn't belive miss that. I'm really happy to find it! Thanks:). And inaddition. It doesn't matter foreign keys are strings with single quotes because I both tried and check that ' ForeginKey('classname')' and 'ForeginKey(classname)' work

Comment: Glad to hear it, I added that as an answer.

Comment: Thank again! And I'm sure that I voted and choosed your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `AdminRoomStateInline` you are passing the `RoomInformation` model, it should be `RoomState.